# LINQ select from first list

Tags: c#, linq

I have list with class 1. In the class I have one more `list<class2>`. In the class 2 I have int HrsID.

How can I select all objects from the `List <Class1>`, where HrsID is == selcetedID?

```
var selected = Skachkis.SelectMany(u => u.Uchastniks).Where(u=>u.HrsID == selcetedID);
```

1. Class1 = Skachkist
2. Class2 = Uchastniks

It's my code its only select all from `List<Class2>` but I need all `List<Class1>` objects.

Comment: `var selected = Skachkis.Where(u => u.Uchastniks.Any(uc=>uc.HrsID == selcetedID)).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var selected = Skachkis.Where(u => u.Uchastniks.Any(h => h.HrsID == horseID));
```